# AnimateTransform not working as expected

Tags: html, svg, animatetransform

My intention was to move the object to a set point (300), stop there for a bit, and then move it again. I tried doing it with animateTransform like this:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" type="translate" dur="12s" start="1s"  fill="freeze"
from="650px" to="300px" repeatCount="1" /> 

<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="2s"  additive="sum" start="20s"  fill="freeze"
from="300px" to="200px" repeatCount="1" />
```

but now the object only moves a 100px after 20s (the first transform is ignored?). I tired using animate instead, but that didnt work as intended either. Any advice on where i went wrong and what i should do to get the animation effect wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The timing attribute is `begin`, not `start`.
2. Leave off the `px` units. While they are legal according to SVG 2, they were not in SVG 1.1, and may not be implemented in some browsers yet.
3. `additive="sum"` means that the transformation is added *on top* of the transformation value resulting from previous animations. At the begin time of the animation the object will jump by the amount of the `from` value and move from there. This is probably not what you wanted to achieve. Either use `additive="replace"` or start all animations with `from="0"` and set `to` to a relative value.

Comment: thank you! I feel a bit embarrassed by the "start" - jesus how did i miss that?